# Rising x - as free variable - to power of element of a list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have the following list:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to have x as a variable to the power of each element in `my_list` so the output would be as follow:

```
[x, x**2, x**3, x**4, x**5]
```

I do as follow:

```
my_new_list = [x**i for i in my_list]
```

But this throws me the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'
```

I wonder this is because `x` is free variable? how does one resolve such cases?

Comment: How do you assign `x`?

Comment: Are you *sure* `x` is a number, and not a tuple? You can't take something that isn't a number to a power, because things that are not numbers do not behave that way. So just find out what `x` actually is, and then convert it into a number.

Comment: I see so there is no way to leave x as free parameter? This is intentional as later I want to make polynomials?

Comment: @chepner Note that `tuple` is the first type in the error message so it refers to the type of `x`, not the type of `i`. So `my_list` likely is what the OP claims.

Comment: @AybikeA According to the error message the problem is with `x`. If the problem were with `i` the places of `tuple` and `int` in the message would be flipped.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Ah, right.

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'
```

This error tells us that `x` is a tuple. This means that somewhere in your code, you have something like

```
x = (1, 2)
```

You cannot raise a tuple to a power. You need to assign it a numerical value, for example:

```
x = 5
my_new_list = [x**i for i in my_list]
```

Of course, you can get the value of `x` from anywhere you wish. It doesn't have to be hardcoded like you do here.

Comment: I see so there is no way to leave x as free parameter? This is intentional as later I want to make polynomials?

Comment: @William Yes, you can leave `x` as a free parameter by defining a **function**. I suggest you check out the official Python tutorial at http://python.org and read about how to create functions in Python. They are similar to mathematical functions in many ways.